# Python2.7 numpy Histogram: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a histogram out of some measurement data. The data have the format below and are saved in a txt-file (altogether about 2000 lines):

```
17.05.2017 06:22:49;144;-1;550;-12
17.05.2017 06:23:19;143;-1;537;-13
```

I would like to write the data in column 3 (550, 537 ...) and 4 (-12,-13 ...) put into a histogram

```
# import    
import sys
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# open file read
try:
    d = open("result_CO2_1705a.txt")
except:
    print("access not successfull")
    sys.exit(0)

# create histogram
daten = d.read()
d.close()
zeilenliste = daten.split("\n")
print zeilenliste

laenge = len(zeilenliste
print laenge

i = 0

li_ppm = []
li_dppm = []
for zeile in zeilenliste:
    if zeile:
        zwliste = zeile.split(";")
        # print zwliste
        li_ppm.append(zwliste[3])


print li_ppm
print li_dppm
ppm_array = np.asarray(li_ppm)
print ppm_array

a = np.histogram(int(ppm_array), 10, laenge, False, None, None)
```

For the last line `a =` I get the error message:

`only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

As I work the first time with `numpy` and histograms, I would be happy to get feedback about the root cause for this error message.

Regards and thank you very much

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a python command which can only work with scalars (i.e. single numbers). This is what the error message tells you.

To convert a numpy array `a` to integer use

```
a.astype(int)
```